# what is the error in this django database?

Tags: django, django-models

```
raise ValueError('The database backend does not accept 0 as a '
ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.
```

This is the error that has occured while making migrations.

```
from django.db import models
# from modules.volunteer.volunteer_models.models import volunteerRegistration
```

the below code is model.py .i would prefer some help guys.

```
class cause(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbl_cause'
        verbose_name_plural = 'causes'


    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    volunteer_no = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    applied_date=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return ('%s' % (self.name))
```

Comment: Apparently in your `tbl_cause` there is a row with an `id` value of `0`.

Comment: so how can i change it

Comment: Well, you should edit the existing data in your table and change the id. Make sure that there are no references to this row. Is this a legacy (i.e. not created by Django) table?